# new line is missing while writing file using NIO

Tags: java

i am trying to copy the content of one file to new file and somehow new line are missing in the new file and its created as one row, i guess its related to buffer position.
following the code that i am using..

```
List<String> lines;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        try
        {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath()), Charset.defaultCharset());
            destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            for (String line : lines)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
                buf.clear();
                buf.put(line.getBytes());
                buf.flip();
                while (buf.hasRemaining())
                {
                    destination.write(buf);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (destination != null)
            {
                destination.close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: You never write the new line characters! (Your misunderstanding might be due to how `readAllLines` behaves: it removes the line separators)

Comment: the question is it supposed to added automatic,or i need to add it in the loop after reading each line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do `buff.put(System.getProperty("line.separator").toString());` before `buf.put(line.getBytes());`

Answer (score 2):

The line where you're writing the bytes:

```
buf.put(line.getBytes());
```

...doesn't include the new line character, you're just writing the bytes of each individual line. You need to write the new line character separately after each instance.

Comment: i added new line to the line inside the loop and its working fine, my question why this happen

Comment: If I have a list containing 3 different "lines" - say "line 1", "line 2", and "line 3", then those lines don't have any new line characters in them. So if you're writing them out, you need to manually put them back in (otherwise you get the behaviour you're observing.)

Answer (score 1):

You might prefer to use Java 7's Files.copy:

```
Files.copy(sourceFile.toPath(), destinationFile.toPath(),
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

One should once write a file copy oneself.
However your current version uses the default platform encoding to read the file *as text*. This goes wrong on UTF-8 (some illegal multibyte sequences), on the `\u0000` nul char, converts the line endings to the default platform ones.

Answer (score 0):

This will include the new line:

```
   ByteBuffer bf = null;
   final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
   bf = ByteBuffer.wrap((yourString+newLine).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8" )));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `System.lineSeparator()` insted of `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

```
buff.put(System.lineSeparator().toString());
```